# Can't install claymate with npm, error: No compatible version found: bower-config@'>=0.2.0 <0.3.0'

Tags: npm, gumby-framework

I'm trying to install claymate with npm with no success. It gives me:

```
mateuss-air:~ mateuspinheiro$ npm install claymate
npm ERR! Darwin 13.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "claymate"
npm ERR! node v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm  v2.0.0
npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: bower-config@'>=0.2.0 <0.3.0'
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget ["0.1.0-rc.1","0.1.0-rc.2","0.1.0-rc.3","0.1.0-rc.4","0.1.0-rc.5","0.2.0-rc.1","0.2.0-rc.2","0.3.0","0.3.1","0.3.3","0.3.4","0.3.5","0.4.0","0.4.1","0.4.2","0.4.3","0.4.4","0.4.5","0.5.0","0.5.1","0.5.2"]
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

Any clues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple: Don't install npm using HomeBrew. It messes things up.

Installed the npm that comes with node and it's perfectly fine now.

Comment: Uninstalled Node with Homebrew, then installed by downloading the package from node.js and things work again.  Thank you!

Comment: That’s it! Thanks! Had a lot of troubles before with npm errors.

Answer (score 4):

I've got an answer for ya. Did that few days ago and finaly got claymate to work. Hope it helps somebody.

U have to install npm@1 ( write it like so ). Then go to install directory ( cause U use nmp2 by default ) and install claymate from that place.
That's it. 
As simple as that and I've spent a lot of time figuring it out.

Answer (score 2):

Does not work for me.
I installed node & npm via the binary installer and updated npm to 2.6

> sudo npm install -g npm

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.1.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "claymate"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: bower-config@'>=0.2.0 <0.3.0'
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget ["0.1.0-rc.1","0.1.0-rc.2","0.1.0-rc.3","0.1.0-rc.4","0.1.0-rc.5","0.2.0-rc.1","0.2.0-rc.2","0.3.0","0.3.1","0.3.3","0.3.4","0.3.5","0.4.0","0.4.1","0.4.2","0.4.3","0.4.4","0.4.5","0.5.0","0.5.1","0.5.2"]
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```